# Ajax - 500 Internal Server Error

Tags: javascript, ajax, xmlhttprequest

I am trying to learn AJAX for this project at work. I have a site that loads medications that a patient is taking.

I call this AJAX function up recursively so that it will append a new table containing a single medication and 7 days worth of history. I am having issues getting the code to execute in FF and IE. Works perfectly fine in chrome. I had alerts displaying the xmlhttp.status and this is what I got:

> xmlhttp.status==500 (internal server
>   error).

I commented out all of my recursion so it is narrowed down to this tid bit of code. ( x keeps track of the number of meds so i know when to stop)

```
function LoadMeds()


  if ( x == MaxMedCount )
  {
      document.getElementById("the_day").value = parseInt(document.getElementById("the_day").value)+7; 
  }
  if ( x == (MaxMedCount - 1) )
  {
      document.getElementById("x").value = x + 1;
      show();
  }
  else
  { 

      if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
      {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
          xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
      }
      else
      {// code for IE6, IE5
          xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
      }
      xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
      {
          try 
          {      
              if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
              {     
                  var div = document.createElement('div');
                  div.innerHTML= xmlhttp.responseText;
                  document.getElementById('MedTable').appendChild(div);
                  document.getElementById("the_med_").value = the_med_;

              }

          }
          catch(e)
          {
              alert("Error");  
          }
      }
      xmlhttp.open("GET","URL with variables passed",true);
      xmlhttp.send();     
      document.getElementById("x").value = x + 1;
  }
```

if more code is needed just let me know.

Answer (score 56, accepted):

The `500 (internal server error)` means something went wrong on the server's side.  It could be several things, but I would start by verifying that the URL and parameters are correct.  Also, make sure that whatever handles the request is expecting the request as a GET and not a POST.

One useful way to learn more about what's going on is to use a tool like [Fiddler](http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/) which will let you watch all HTTP requests and responses so you can see exactly what you're sending and the server is responding with.

If you don't have a compelling reason to write your own Ajax code, you would be far better off using a library that handles the Ajax interactions for you.  [jQuery](http://jquery.com/) is one option.

Comment: `Also, make sure that whatever handles the request is expecting the request as a GET and not a POST ` - How do  you use the jQuery.post() method then? If I'd like to write to the database, shouldn't I be making Ajax request as POST

Comment: @buffer His example showed `xmlhttp.open("GET", "URL with variables passed", true);`, so the comment about the server expecting a GET was specific to his code.  Use a POST from the client if your server request handling is expecting a POST.

Comment: I got the same error , I know I am sending a lot of ajax requests to server and asking for lots of data.I expect few requests to fail sometimes. I only want to hide that 500 error popup and don't want the end user to see that the request was failed . How do i do that ? I am using jquery ajax method.

Answer (score 15):

I think your return string data is very long. so the JSON format has been corrupted.
You should change the max size for JSON data in this way :

Open the Web.Config file and paste these lines into the configuration section

```
<system.web.extensions>
  <scripting>
    <webServices>
      <jsonSerialization maxJsonLength="50000000"/>
    </webServices>
  </scripting>
</system.web.extensions>
```

Comment: Looking for it all around the web and your answer saved the day! Thank you very much!

Comment: Great Answer! Default is 100KB, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/1151993/1845672

Answer (score 6):

This may be an incorrect parameter to your SOAP call; look at the format of the parameter(s) in the 'data:' json section - this is the payload you are passing over - parameter and data wrapped in JSON format.

Google Chrome's debugging toolbar has some good tools to verify parameters and look at error messages - for example, start with the Console tab and click on the URL which errors or click on the network tab.  You will want to view the message's headers, response etc...

Comment: The hint for console Tab+ click on the URL is an excellent tip!  this will point out errors in parameters.  The error message supplied for this case is very specific and helped me debug my ajax, 500 Internal Server Error quickly!

Answer (score 2):

Uncomment the following line : `[System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptService]`

Service will start working fine.

```
[WebService(Namespace = "http://tempuri.org/")]
```

```
 [WebServiceBinding(ConformsTo = WsiProfiles.BasicProfile1_1)]
```

> To allow this Web Service to be called from script, using ASP.NET
>   AJAX,  uncomment the following line.

```
[System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptService]

public class WebService : System.Web.Services.WebService 
{
```

Answer (score 1):

Had the very same problem, then I remembered that for security reasons ASP doesn't expose the entire error or stack trace when accessing your site/service remotely, same as not being able to test a `.asmx` web service remotely, so I remoted into the sever and monitored my dev tools, and only then did I get the notorious message "Could not load file or assembly `'Newtonsoft.Json, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=30ad4fe6b2a6aeed'` or one of its dep...".

So log on the server and debug from there.

Answer (score 1):

One must use `behavior: JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet` in Post `Json Return` in C#

Answer (score 0):

I fixed an error like this changing the places of the routes in routes.php, for example i had something like this:

```
Route::resource('Mensajes', 'MensajeriaController');
Route::get('Mensajes/modificar', 'MensajeriaController@modificarEstado');
```

and then I put it like this:

```
Route::get('Mensajes/modificar', 'MensajeriaController@modificarEstado');
Route::resource('Mensajes', 'MensajeriaController');
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error. It turns out that the cause was that the back end method was expecting different json data. In my Ajax call i had something like this:

```
$.ajax({
        async: false,
        type: "POST",
        url: "http://13.82.13.196/api.aspx/PostAjax",
        data: '{"url":"test"}',
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
    });
```

Now in my WebMethod, inside my C# backend code i had declared my endpoint like this:

```
public static string PostAjax(AjaxSettings settings)
```

Where AjaxSettings was declared:

```
public class AjaxSettings
{
    public string url { get; set; }
}
```

The problem then was that the mapping between my ajax call and my back-end endpoint was not the same. As soon as i changed my ajax call to the following, it all worked well!

```
var data ='{"url":"test"}';    
$.ajax({
    async: false,
    type: "POST",
    url: "http://13.82.13.196/api.aspx/PostAjax",
    data: '{"settings":'+data+'}',
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    dataType: "json"
});
```

I had to change the data variable inside the Ajax call in order to match the method signature exactly.