# Remove default submit on modal form button

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, forms, model-view-controller

I have a parent form that is using a modal form to update it. Once the user is finished with the modal form:

1. I want it to close the modal form
2. Trigger a post-back which will call a controller function to update a database table
3. Avoid redirecting using the default submit action (`e.preventDefault()`)

My problem is that if I remove the default submit event, no post-back occurs and my database table stays unmodified. I am using AJAX to modified the text on the parent form to reflect the user updates.

How can I force a post back without leaving the parent form? I do not want to reload the webpage; only update values, close the modal form and trigger a post event to call an update function.

**NOTE: If I omit the `preventDefault()` event, the webpage always redirects to the url: `/client/UpdateClientDetails/' + id`**

Please see below for my code snippets:

**AJAX snippet**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$('.btn-primary').click(function (e) {
    $.ajax({
        url: '/Client/UpdateClientDetails',
        type: 'POST',            
        dataType: 'json',
        data: newClient = {
            address1: $("#clientAddress1-@Model.Id").val(),
            address2: $("#clientAddress2-@Model.Id").val(),
            city: $("#clientCity-@Model.Id").val(),
            province: $("#clientProvince-@Model.Id").val(),
            postalCode: $("#clientPostalCode-@Model.Id").val(),
            phoneNumber: $("#clientPhoneNumber-@Model.Id").val()
        },
        cache: false,
        contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
        success: function (data) {
            $("#Address1-@Model.Id").text(newClient.address1);
            $("#Address2-@Model.Id").text(newClient.address2);
            $("#City-@Model.Id").text(newClient.city);
            $("#Province-@Model.Id").text(newClient.province);
            $("#PostalCode-@Model.Id").text(newClient.postalCode);
            $("#PhoneNumber-@Model.Id").text(newClient.phoneNumber);

            $("#dialog-actions").dialog('close');
        },
        error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) { alert(xhr.status); alert(thrownError); }
    });
});
```

**Beginning of modal form**

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("UpdateClientDetails", "Client", FormMethod.Post, attributes))
{
    //HTML Helpers & other things here
}
```

**Controller method I want to invoke**

```
[HttpPost]
public void UpdateClientDetails(Client newClientDetails)
{
    _clientService.UpdateClient(newClientDetails);
}
```

Comment: Don't use a submit button, just `<button type="button" id="save">Save</button>` and handle it's `.click()` event. But your script is not sending anything data to the controller - you need to add `data: $('form').serialize(),` and its not clear what you think all that code in your `success` callback is supposed to be doing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `<input type="submit">`, when inside a form element, will submit the form when clicked unless you return false or `event.preventDefault();`

Omitting preventDefault() will always submit the form because your input is a "SUBMIT". `e.preventDefault()` it's just like returning false, nothing is really invoked in the server.

**Use button instead of submit**

Since you are already using AJAX you could do something like this.

Update your controller method to return JsonResult.

```
    [HttpPost]
public JsonResult UpdateClientDetails(Client newClientDetails)
{
    _clientService.UpdateClient(newClientDetails);
    return Json("Success", JsonRequestBehavior.DenyGet);
}
```

Javascript.

```
$(".btn-primary").click(function () {
    $.ajax({
                url: 'URL to your json method',
                type: 'POST',
                dataType: 'json',
                data: 'Build your JSON object and set it here',
                cache: false,
                contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
                success: function (data) {

                    var returnValue;
                    try {
                        returnValue = data;

                        //Do your logic. 
                        $("#dialog-actions").dialog('close');

                    } catch (e) {
                        // error

                        return;
                    }


                },
                error: function () { alert("Something went wrong! Please contact the system admin.") }
            })
});
```

Comment: I'm trying to implement your structure but the `error()` function is always hit. Using Firefox's debugger, I get a 500 Internal Server Error. The **request** header is `Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8` but the **response** header is `Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8`. Would this discrepancy most likely be the cause of the error?

Comment: Would you share the URL you are using in your JSON call?

Comment: The URL is: `'Client/UpdateClientDetails'`.

Comment: Use this Instead  url: '@Url.Action("UpdateClientDetails", "Controller Name")', OR add "/" to your URL '/Client/UpdateClientDetails'

Comment: Didn't realize I missed a forward slash.. I have updated the OP to show the new AJAX call. Still receiving an error. I am new to JSON so maybe there is something wrong with my understanding of it.

Comment: Replace your error call to this error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
        alert(xhr.status);
        alert(thrownError);
      } This way you can actually see the real error.

Comment: It shows `500 Internal Server Error`. Not really sure where to start taking a look to try and troubleshoot. OP updated once more.

Comment: Check this out buddy.. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4789613/ajax-500-internal-server-error

Comment: Modified the `url` parameter to `/Client/` and this fixed my `500` error. I was mistaking this URL for the modal form instead of the destination URL. In this case I would assume it would be the default webpage. However a message stating that there is a JSON syntax error appears. I'll take it from here. Your help was much appreciated Moe!