# Update database using onclick event with Ajax

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, ajax

I am trying to pass some values to a mysql table but I do something wrong. I call this function from somewhere:

```
function updatebets(postid, bet, betamount){

alert(postid + " " + bet + " " + betamount);


 $.ajax({
      type: 'POST',
      url: 'current.php',
      data: {bankpostid: postid, bankbet: bet, bankbetamount: betamount},
      success: function(){
          alert('works');
      },
      error: function(){
         alert('something went wrong');
      }
 });

}
```

This is the current.php page:

```
<?php
global $current_user, $wpdb;
$uid = $current_user->ID;


$postid = $_POST['bankpostid'];
$bet = $_POST['bankbet'];
$betamount = $_POST['bankbetamount'];


$sql = "INSERT INTO bets (postid, uid, bet, betamount) VALUES ('$postid', '$uid', '$bet' , '$betamount')";
$wpdb->query($sql);

?>
```

The fields "postid, uid, bet, betamount" are the name fields of the table I want to update. I get the error 'something went wrong'. I am working with wordpress, the page current.php is in the theme folder.

Comment: Is the extra `'` in `''bankpostid'` actually in your code, or just a typo here?

Comment: Yea I just noticed it. Now the code is running but the table doesn't get updated

Comment: What are you trying to do? You want to update or insert a record; first try to accomplish task without ajax?

Answer (score 0):

I know, you need update data in your database but you run SQL INSERT DATA.

If you want Update data in your database you must use SQL UPDATE.

Here is the example

```
$sql = "UPDATE bets SET postid='$postid', uid='$uid', bet='$bet' , betamount='$betamount' WHERE betsprimary='$betsprimary'
```

The `betsprimary='$betsprimary'` syntax you can replace with primary key coloumn and the value in your table.

Comment: Actually the problem is that the current.php page doesn't get called. Is there any mistake in the ajax syntax?

Comment: Can you attach your folder structure? So I can see how to write in your code

Comment: I don't know how to do that. I am working with wordpress. The page current.php is inside the theme folder.

Comment: If you check your console is show the error? file not found or anything?
If I didn't know your folder structure I can't help you write right path your current.php file

Comment: When you run your codes what you get? 'works' or 'something went wrong'

Comment: something went wrong, so I guess the url path must be false if the ajax code is ok

Comment: It's in another .php file. I believe the problem is that I don't import the current.php file in my code. It's location is in wp-content/themes/mytheme/current.php. Any idea how and where to import it in my code?

Comment: I included it using include (TEMPLATEPATH . '/current.php'); but I still getting "something went wrong" error.

Comment: try remove the backslash (TEMPLATEPATH . 'current.php')

Comment: How can I access network console? I removed "/" but I have the same error.

Comment: What browser are you using it?
If you using Chrome, just click Network tab. and you can see your request to your server.

Comment: Ok so I changed the path of current.php file to absolute path. Now when I run the code,in the browsers console I get the status error  [HTTP/1.0 500 Internal Server Error 16ms]. Any idea how can I fix this? It's about permissions?

Comment: maybe this link can help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4789613/ajax-500-internal-server-error